# wix generated bootstrapper is not a valid NT application

Tags: wix, windows-nt

We generated with WiX 3.7 a bootstrapper exe, and tried it on XP, Win7 and it works fine. But on an NT (4.0) machine we get "... is not a valid NT application" error when starting the exe. Is thre a previous version of WiX that supports WinNT, or do we have to write an own bootstrapper?

Thanks in advance, Franky

Answer (score 1):

The WiX toolset only supports Windows XP and later. The modern Microsoft compilers C-runtime create that minimum requirement. Unfortunately, you'll need to create your own executables for NT4 and Windows 2000.